# How do I declare a global variable in PHP I can use across templates?

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress, it calls header.php then whatever template name or the page requested.  How can I declare a variable in my php header which I can then refer to in my other templates?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The answer pretty much depends what you need it for. If you are developing a theme and want to keep values constant through all files you can place them in `functions.php` in the theme directory, which is always loaded. Variables defined there should be available everywhere in the theme. This works if you distribute the theme.

If you want to modify an existing theme for your needs on your own installation, you can either put them in `wp-config.php`, as suggested, or (a cleaner method) you can [create a child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) of the theme you want to change. This will keep it separate from the wordpress core and will prevent theme updates from overwriting your changes.

I just tried it using `functions.php`:

functions.php:

```
$variable = "value";
```

header.php:

```
global $variable;
echo $variable;
```

works for me.

Comment: ok, but how do I actually declare it since I tried global `$domain = 'http://mydomain.com` and `global $domain = 'http://mydomain.com` in both functions.php and then wp-config, when I then tried `echo $domain; ` in my header.php, it was empty

Comment: the correct syntax would be: `global $variable; $variable = "value";`. I don't think `global` is necessary though.

Comment: so I declare it as global first, then define it?  Or you mean when I echo is I have to echo global $variable?

Comment: I was not entirely correct, global is needed, but rather in the template file than at the definition. Answer updated.

Comment: Correct method here: [WP Forum thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/passing-php-variable-between-template-files) - And I found that you can declare the value in say page.php instead of functions.php if you like (just declare it before calling `wp_head()` )

Answer (score 10):

You can declare it like so (In functions.php):

```
global $domain;
$domain = 'http://www.mydomain.com/';
```

You can echo the domain of the WordPress site like this, though..

```
<?php bloginfo('site_url');?>
```

Or

```
$url = site_url();
echo $url;
```

Or as a function, in functions.php

```
function displayMyDomain() {
  global $domain; // you probably don't actually need to set it global as it is a function
  $domain = 'http://www.domain.com/';
  echo $domain;
}
```

Then anywhere, use `<?php displayMyDomain(); ?>`

Comment: ok, I just tried `global $domain='http://mydomain.com;` and it doesn't like that.

Comment: You can't do that - global $domain; and then $domain = 'x'; would work. Not that I can't assign something to the variable $domain and declare it global.

Comment: ahh I worked it out.  I declare it somewhere else.  I then in my template I want to use it in declare it global and can then echo it.  So my question now is, what does the global word do?  Does php then look through all the files used for the current page and find the variable?

Comment: the `global` keyword pulls variables in a context where they would normally not be available, for example inside a function. See the documentation for details: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: I note that you want it to be the domain. Can't you just use a WP function to get this or is it custom? Note my updated answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a easier to understand solution with a function

Comment: thanks, it was an external domain I needed so I couldn't use <?php bloginfo('site_url');?>.

Answer (score 4):

You can define them in `wp-config.php` file.

The config file is never updated so your Wordpress installation will have those variables over time even if you update it.

```
<?php
  require_once('wp-config.php');
  echo $domain;
?>
```

Comment: ok, but how do I actually declare it since I tried global $domain = 'http://mydomain.com and global $domain = 'http://mydomain.com in wp-config, when I then tried echo $domain; in my header.php, it was empty

Comment: I would rather have it it functions.php as this is always being called.  Can't you declare it in functions and use it again in header.php?

Comment: You can add it in `functions.php` for that custom theme, but you won't be able to use them in other themes.

Comment: thats fine, but how?  How do I initially declare it and how to I call it?

Comment: Like I said, make `$domain = 'http://www.mydomain.com';` then call the code from my answer.

Comment: yes, if I was declaring it in wp-config, but I want to declare it in functions.php, I don't understand why I need to `require_once` it when functions gets called already by wordpress before the HTML templates are loaded

Comment: in functions you can set the variable directly and call it directly without any require.

Comment: yes, I can call it without any require in functions.php, but I wanted to call it from another file...

Answer (score 3):

Another way to define global consts in Wordpress, if for best practice purpose you don't want to add a variable to your WP-config (to keep it clean ?). And for some reasons your variable scope is not getting the global scope everywhere in your website.

You can simply use :

```
define( 'MY_VARIABLE', 'My Value' );
```

For more information about consts scope :
http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me.  Used this in a WordPress template.  Using global or $GLOBALS did not work!  Not sure why!

Answer (score -3):

I think **php session** is one of the way to use as a global variable on **Wordpress**.

**1. Functions.php**

```
if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}
```

**2. Any `.php` file where you want set or get global variables**

- get variable

  ```
  if(isset($_SESSION['global_var'])) {
      $local_var = $_SESSION['global_var'];
  }
  ```
- set variable

  ```
  $_SESSION['global_var'] = "This is global var";
  ```