# Set root for images folder in wordpress with php

Tags: php, wordpress, path, root

my problem is to set a root variable for images without writing all the path in Wordpress with php.
My situation is:

```
<img src="http://localhost/business/wp-content/themes/enigma-child/images/sottocategorie/animaliDomestici/cane.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
```

i want this situation ($root=http://localhost/business/wp-content/themes/enigma-child):

```
<img src="root/images/sottocategorie/animaliDomestici/cane.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
```

where do I set this root variable in wordpress? there is a way to take the images from the gallery?
Thx for answers

Answer (score 1):

Since you are referencing from a child theme the way you dynamically call an image is by using the `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` function.

Eg. `<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/image.png"  alt="your image">`

For $root as your variable, would be best to insert this as a global variable in your functions.php or header.php . This way you do not modify core code but extend from your child theme.

*[How do I declare a global variable in PHP I can use across templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638734/how-do-i-declare-a-global-variable-in-php-i-can-use-across-templates)*

*https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri*

Comment: I tested the code that you suggested, but it does not work because my situation is to use the img tag within the switch. I show my situation:
`case 1:
                        echo ("<p><div class='textMain'> Animali Domestici </div> </p>");
                        echo ('<p><img class="enigma_img_responsive image_animal" src="<?php get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/sottocategorie/animaliDomestici/cane.jpg"></p>');
                        break;`

Comment: You try and use `<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/image.png"  alt="image">`

Comment: This works, but with php code in html. My problem is the reverse html code into php, I can not read the way you've shown me. Look at this picture to understand my problem:
[link](https://postimg.org/image/52npf1rmb/)

Comment: You can try making the link path relative like so `<img src="/wp-content/themes/enigma-child/images/sottocategorie/animaliDomestici/cane.jpg" > ` .

Comment: I try the link path relative, and not work. Show the try relative path to link:
[link](https://postimg.org/image/9gwf6f233/).
Where the problem may be? can not interpret well the html code inside the PHP switch?

Comment: WordPress is a bit tricky with folders but the recommended way is to use the working function I gave you but ensure you are concatenating correctly so that the HTML can render correctly in PHP.
`<p class="text-center"> bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/images/sottocategorie/a‌​nimaliDomestici/cane‌​.jpg" class="img thumbnail img-responsive">  </p>`

Comment: It does not work, it is true paths with wp images are very difficult to connect. If I put the pictures in the gallery wp? how can I get to this path? Thx

Comment: Since you are really battling the best bet would for you to put your code on Github or Bitbucket. I will then be able to help you resolve this.