# How to get the value of the number of posts per page in the function.php file?

Tags: php, wordpress

From Wordpress I get data on the number of posts per page `$posts_per_page`

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => $categories,
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
);
$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

How now to get this number in functions.php?

```
wp_register_script( 'loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/load-more.js', '', '', true );
wp_localize_script( 'loadmore', 'loadmore_params', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'posts' => $wp_query->query_vars,
    'current_page' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1,
    'max_page' => $posts_per_page,  
) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'loadmore' );
```

Comment: you can store your $posts_per_page in a GLOBAL variable show you can find it in you functions.php also.

Comment: I tried to use a global variable, but as a result, I get null. What am I doing wrong?

```global $get_posts_per_page;
$get_posts_per_page = $posts_per_page;
```

Comment: check this answer. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638734/how-do-i-declare-a-global-variable-in-php-i-can-use-across-templates)

Comment: In my case, it does not work

Answer (score 0):

function.php

```
function custom_posts_per_page($query) {
    if (is_home()) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', $posts_per_page);
    }
    if (is_search()) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', $posts_per_page);
    }
    if (is_archive()) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', $posts_per_page);
    } //endif
} //function
```